# Electronic Devices and airport security checks

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, electronic-items

I have seen recently that the US and UK have announced that all 'electronic devices' will have to be 'powered up' before allowing them on board a plane, I believe for the UK it's on all flights though I am not sure about the US.

Starting next month I am going to doing a fair amount of travelling overseas and I am concerned about some particular items I will be carrying like an external HDD, Apple TV, Apple wifi router and a mini PC (similar size to the Apple TV).

These devices don't have a battery and so can't be 'powered up', even if they are plugged in to the mains without a screen or keyboard you wouldn't really be able to tell they were actually 'on'.

I have tried to find out what the 'rules' are but they seem intentionally vague, does anyone have experience of carrying similar devices recently and know whether there might be a problem with the above.

I don't really want to end up at the airport facing losing a lot of expensive equipment and valuable data or missing the flight.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but I don't think it really is a duplicate, I wouldn't have any issue with explaining to someone what I was carrying, my question is really regardless of whatever explanation I could give to the security staff if I can't 'power up' will the stuff get confiscated!

Comment: Rob, are you taking apple tv onboard?

Comment: ok, I just noticed that apple tv is a small device :) I thought it is a Tv :D

Comment: Well I will take it with me, I don't mind checking it in if I have too, FYI it's just a small black box about 4"x4" it's not an actual "TV" ... confusing I know :)

Comment: Rob, these wont be a problem, it wont fit a bomb inside, I have explain the logic behind these new security measures in the other answer, same thing applies here.

Comment: Thanks for that, I sort of understood the 'logic' of what the rules were about and don't really have a problem with the what they are trying to achieve but often when the actual 'rules' reach the end of the chain of command 'logic' tends to go out the window :)

Answer (score 0):

The checks only relate to hand luggage.  Check it in.

I've done a dozen flights out of the UK since this alert, and I haven't been challenged yet to carry this out.